# Is there a way to make "encapsulated" reusable components in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, sass, components

I have been searching for new approaches to Wordpress theme development and came across an array of different options that allow you to follow the most diverse approaches, like for example the "Roots Sage" starter theme or the "Themosis Framework" or even "Flynt". But these, despite the fact that they solve very interesting problems, are not exactly what I need.

I am looking for a way to create custom scalable and re-usable components that will live inside a php file and that would have all the logic, html and styles inside them (SCSS, HTML, Javascript and PHP). In modern javascript frameworks, for example in Vue, we have a structure where you can have everything related to a component inside the same file using the `<script>` `<template>` and `<style>` tags.

Do you know of any way I can follow the same principle of those frameworks and for example be able to achieve something like this?

`custom-faq-block.php`

```
<style>
//here we would have the sass that would need to be compiled in some way.
</style>

<template>
// here we would have the html and for example fetch a custom post type using php
</template>

<script>
//here we would use any jQuery or vanilla javascript to be used in this component
</script>
```

This component would then be loaded using the standard `get_template_part()` function from wordpress.

Does this make sense?
Do you know of any way I can do this? or any extension that reads my inline `sass` in some way and appends it to a global .css stylesheet?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: First, WordPress doesn’t have native SCSS support, you’d need to add a plugin or a custom build step. Second, although not exactly 100% what you are looking for, the overall pattern is currently handled by Gutenberg [blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/)

Comment: In my company’s theme development we use ACF with Flexible Layouts to define components, and we built an autoloader that is more similar to what you are talking about. The component loader looks in a specific location for a PHP file named according to the component’s name, along with CSS and JS files named similarly which it enqueues.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your comments. I was thinking that maybe with scssphp extension we could somehow make the extension compile that inline sass and maybe using a gulp task to watch for changes in the file and run the compiler everytime there is a change in the component files.. can you share an example of the autoloader you are talking about?

Comment: Several years back we built half a dozen or WordPress sites with build scripts, mostly for transpiling CSS and JS to legacy browsers, and we finally migrated the last of those to regular boring CSS/JS about six months ago, so I'm soured for the pattern in general for WordPress sites. We also have Symfony sites with webpack which works great, I just don't think it works in a WordPress environment, at least for my company's flow. I can't speak to any plugins. A gulp task would be daemon/cron-based which hopefully doesn't break.

Comment: As for the autoloader, I can show you the [current one](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/vendi-component-loader) which doesn't have the CSS and JS loading, that's under active development and not in a public repo currently. That, along with our [base theme](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/vendi-starter-theme/blob/master/index.php) is intended to reduce the number of files in the root of the theme so that more HTML can be shared. We divide the logic up into templates that are shell-based, page or component.

Comment: thnak you for your contribution! I will explore the repos you sent. meanwhile after some testing around and some brainstorming I came up with some code that implements the vision I shared above.... It has some imperfections though.. However, I will share it as an aswer and maybe some people can give their input to make it better!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have been playing around and after some trial and error I have come up with a small script that allows people to have a structure similar to what I have asked in my first question. I have created a repo for it, but please find below a detailed description. I know that this is not polished yet but might be the start of something interesting.

---

So I have created a small script that relies on **Gulp** and **SCSSPHP** to compile sass used inside components that are defined inside PHP files and that follow something like the Vue.Js component definition style.

[Link for the Github repo of Compomatic](https://github.com/Slaveworx/compomatic)

This will allow you to have something like this:

`my-component.php`

```html
<!-- ##### COMPONENT STYLES ##### -->
<style>
//Here I will define all my sass for the component
#my-component{
   
 h3{
   color:red;
  }

 p{
   font-size: 12px;
  }
}
</style>

<!-- ##### COMPONENT BODY ##### -->
<div id="#my-component">
<h3>Hello!</h3>
<p><?php echo somefunction(foo);?></p>
</div>

<!-- ##### COMPONENT SCRIPTS ##### -->
<script>
//some component specific javascript will be here....
</script>
```

These files should be created inside a `./components` folder inside your wordpress theme.

[image: file tree]

## How to Use - Instructions

**1** - Make sure you have composer and npm installed in your system.

**2** - Go to the wordpress theme where you want to install the compiler and run:

`composer require scssphp/scssphp`

**3** - Copy the file `compomatic.php` and `gulpfile.js` to the theme root. Also, create a new folder called `components` where your components will live.

**4** - Include the following line to your theme’s `functions.php`:

```php
require_once(“compomatic.php”)
```

**5**- Run the following command:
`npm init`

**6** - Run the following command:
`npm install gulp gulp-phpunit gulp-shell gulp-watch --save-dev`

**7** - Then run `gulp watch`

From there onwards, all changes to the components directory will trigger the sass compiler during dev.
The folder for the outputed compiled css and also the folder for additional scss includes (for example your own mixin collection, variables, general styles, etc) shall be modified to your liking inside the file `compomatic.php`.

These are the variables you can modify:

```php
/*******************************************
* CUSTOMIZE THESE VARIABLES TO YOUR LIKING *
********************************************/

$output_file  =  './assets/css/test.css';  // Define output file
$output_dir  =  dirname($output_file);  // Get the directory of the output file
$additional_includes  =  './src/scss/test.scss';  //add any additional includes, fo example a set of mixins, variables or general styles...
```

## How To Load Components  ?

Compomatic has an helper function to load components.
What this helper function does is getting the components and trimming out everything that is inside the `<style>` tags. That way, the content of those tags does not pollute the DOM as those styles are already being served from the compiled css.

To use the helper function you just need to do it like this:

```php
load_component("/components/my-component");
```

### Note:

Do not forget to enqueue the generated CSS file. The default location where Compomatic saves the output file is: `./assets/css/components.css`

```php
wp_register_style('components',get_template_directory_uri() .  '/assets/css/components.css',array(),'1.0');
// Enqueue components stylesheet.
wp_enqueue_style('components');
```